# I want to click on a square to fly a message that displays the number that is within each square with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

### JQUERY

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        var pars = $("p");
        for( i=0; i<pars.length; i++ ) {
        alert("Found paragraph: " + pars[i].innerHTML);
    });
});
```

### CSS

```css
.container {
     padding:10%
}

[class*="col-"] > div {
     background:white;height:200px;width:200px;
     padding:20px;
     margin:13%;
 }

.value {
     position: absolute;
     top: 90px;
     left: 130px;
}
```

### HTML

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4  col-sm-5">
<div style="background-color:pink"><h1 id="test" class="value">1</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
<div style="background-color:pink" ><h1 id="test" class="value">2</h1></div>
</div>

<div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
<div style="background-color:yellow" ><h1 id="test" class="value">3</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4  col-sm-5">
<div style="background-color:yellow"><h1 id="test" class="value">4</h1></div>
</div>  

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
<div style="background-color:blue"><h1 id="test" class="value">5</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4  col-sm-5">
<div style="background-color:blue" ><h1 id="test" class="value">6</h1></div>
</div>  `
```

Every time I click a box I want to display an alert with the number that is within the box.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Dimitar Popov**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2429802/dimitar-popov) is right to suggest using `alert($(this).find(".value").html());` and adding it do a `click` handler.

You shouldn't add a handler to all `<div>`s, though. Instead, only target those divs that correspond with the squares :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[class*="col-"] > div').click(function(){
        alert($(this).find(".value").html());
    });
});
```

See [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/42gz2tkL/8/) for a working demo. I also made a few other minor improvements to your code there...

Answer (score 0):

When you are attaching listeners, you get the DOM element, for which the event has happened with `this`. So in your case the code for alerting the value of every h1 when the corresponding div is clicked is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("div").click(function(){
alert($(this).find(".value").html());
});
```